# Para que serve a palavra "self" em Python?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, funções, método, palavras-reservadas

desculpem a minha ignorância no assunto pois estou começando agora na linguagem Python, e por esse mesmo motivo queria saber para que funciona a palavra reservada "self".

Desde já agradeço a atenção e paciência!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A palavra reservada self serve para que você referencie o próprio

objeto(instância) tanto quando você for fazer uso de metódos como quando for

utilizar atributos pertencentes e este objeto.

Seque o exemplo:

```
class Ponto(object):               #(1)   
    def __init__(self, x):         #(2)
        self.x = x                 #(3)
    def set_x(self, valor):        #(4)
        self.x = valor             #(5)

objeto_1 = Ponto(2)     # inicilizamos um objeto com x = 2
objeto_2 = Ponto(3)     # inicializamos outro objeto com x = 4
print(objeto_1.x)       # imprime o valor de x do objeto_1 que é 2
objeto_1.set_x(7)       # alteramos o valor x de objeto_1 para 7
print(objeto_1.x)       # imprime o valor de x do objeto_1 que é 7
objeto_2.set_x(5)       # alteramos o valor de x do objeto_2 para 5
print(objeto_2.x)       # imprime o valor de x do objeto_2 que é 5
```

Na linha (1) criamos a Classe Ponto

Na linha (2) inicializamos a Classe Ponto e pedimos que sejam passados dois

parâmetros (self, x) não se preocupe com o self, pois metódos em python quando

chamados passam o objeto(instância) como primeiro parâmetro, ou seja, self é

uma refêrencia ao próprio objeto em questão.Sei que é difícil de se assimilar

mas pense vou tentar deixar isso claro pense comigo:

Uma classe nada mais é do que uma fábrica de objetos certo ? Ou seja posso criar

infinitos objetos, mas como visto acima eu inicializei dois objetos para a class

Ponto (objeto_1, objeto_2), quando eu decidi alterar o x do objeto_1 como o

interpretador sabia qual era o objeto em questão ???

Isso se faz graças ao self que é sempre passado como primeiro parâmetro.

Desculpem ter me alongado mas é que farei tudo que puder para ajudar.

Comment: Sua paragrafação está confusa. Você realmente desejava escrever do jeito que está sendo exibido?

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação amigo!

Answer (score 0):

O palavra reservada `self` é utilizada como referência do mesmo objeto.
recomendo a leitura [SignificadoDoSelf](https://wiki.python.org.br/SignificadoDoSelf)  e [IntroducaoOop](https://wiki.python.org.br/IntroducaoOop)